# how to hide 3rd row from table while exporting to excel?

Tags: javascript, php, export-to-excel

i have a jquery code to export into excel from html table but it is leaving one blank row while exporting, i am using bootstrap for table designing, how to remove this blank row while exporting into excel. i got the code form [here](https://gist.github.com/insin/1031969)

my php/table code is-

```
<table id="empTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead class="table-th">
        <tr valign="middle">
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>                
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>City</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                           
            <?php 
            $count = 0;            
            foreach ($record as $key => $data) { $count+=1; 
            $employee_name=$data['employee_name'];
            $city=$data['city'];
            $dob=$data['dob'];                         
            echo "<tr>";                
            echo "<td>".$count."</td>";                
            echo "<td>".$employee_name."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$dob."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$city."</td>";           
            echo "</tr>";
            ?>                
        <?php } ?> 
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="table-tf">  
        <tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

and my js code is-

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table,table_title ,name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: '<center><b>'+table_title+'</b></center><br/>'+table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

and my output is-

```
Employee Detail         
SN  Employee Name   DOB City

1   John    12-18-1983  Texas
2   Sarah   08-26-1985  CA
3   David   06-15-1986  HX
4   Nick    06-14-1982  Miami
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('tr td:first-child:empty').closest('tr').hide()
```

**How it works:**

-Select all first td elements in tr

-Filter elements to only get empty among them.

-get the closest tr element and hide it.